# SSH public/private key authentication from AFS mounted home directory

Tags: macos, ssh, file-permissions, gitolite

I'm trying to set up access to a gitolite-managed git server from an OS X machine with home directory mounted by AFS.  Unix permissions are ignored by AFS, and based on my understanding of the problem, there is an OS X permission-faking fix in AFS that sets all permissions to 666 so that Finder can still open files locally.

When you try to authenticate to the git server you get

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @ 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
Permissions 0666 for '$HOME/.ssh/id_dsa' are too open
```

because ssh thinks the private key is too visible (it's not since permissions are actually managed by AFS ACLs). `chmod` has no effect on the local unix permissions.

Here's a Nabble thread about the problem I found that wasn't much help:

http://old.nabble.com/User-friendly-Mac-OS-X-patch-causes-SSH-hardship-tt8851573.html#a8851573

Does anyone know a work around?  Is there anyway to fake the permissions of .ssh to something like 700?

Comment: Ahhh, good ol' AFS (I used to work on AFS back when it first got started at Universities close to 20 years ago).  Anyways, can you create a symbolic link from .ssh in your AFS directory back to some directory on your local machine?  You definitely do *not* want to have private keys available to anyone but your authenticated, tokened self on AFS.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for your comment.  I'm at CMU, where AFS is basically part of the architecture.  And by that, I mean not just the system architecture, but the physical architecture.  I'm pretty sure buildings would fall down without it.  Unfortunately, creating a symbolic link wouldn't help, since the symbolic link itself would have permissions 666, even if the actual private key was somewhere safe.

Answer (score 0):

You could try modifying your /etc/ssh_config file to use a specified identity file.  Inserting something like this, perhaps:

```
Host <gitolite-server-host>
  IdentityFile <identity-file-location> # this defaults to your ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  User <gitolite-username>
```

Comment: This does assume you're just trying to connect from one machine

Answer (score 0):

The relevant source code from the 6.6 version of the OpenSSH `ssh` utility is below. Basically, ssh requires the key file to be mode 0600 (or more restrictive) if the file is owned by the user running ssh. If the file is owned by some other ID, then it could have any permissions that allow it to be read.

So, hypothetically you could work around this restriction by using a key file belonging to another account. I realize that's not very helpful.

If someone has the necessary skills, a more practical solution would be to build a customized version of `ssh` from the [portable source code](http://www.openssh.com/portable.html).

```c
    if (fstat(fd, &st) < 0)
            return 0;
    /*
     * if a key owned by the user is accessed, then we check the
     * permissions of the file. if the key owned by a different user,
     * then we don't care.
     */
#ifdef HAVE_CYGWIN
    if (check_ntsec(filename))
#endif
    if ((st.st_uid == getuid()) && (st.st_mode & 077) != 0) {
            error("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
            error("@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @");
            error("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
            error("Permissions 0%3.3o for '%s' are too open.",
                (u_int)st.st_mode & 0777, filename);
            error("It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.");
            error("This private key will be ignored.");
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
```